# Wordpress multilingual site using page-id.php files

Tags: multi-language, plugin-wpml, plugin-polylang

I'm building a `Wordpress` site which I hope to offer in three languages namely:

1. English
2. Spanish
3. French

In the past I've always built out my sites by creating the pages via the backend, recording the ids for each page and creating php files with the following naming convention:  `page-123.php` and including `get_header()` and `get_footer`. This gives me the flexibility to then go and code out my pages appropriately.

My concern is how can I achieve multi linugal functionality if I'm doing this!? I know there are 2 main plugins which can achieve this `polylang` and `wpml` but I dont' know if they support hte way I'm developing out the site.

Has anyone any experience doing something like this and could you please advise ?

Answer (score 2):

I have developed pages in that manner and if you are using WordPress functions and follow WP Codex it is same situation as if you developed custom page template. Just follow [I18n for WordPress Developers](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers) and you will be fine.